# LDAP filter for numeric value

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

How can I change this query to find only records with numeric value of telephoneNumber attribute?

```
(&(objectClass=user)(telephoneNumber=*)(MemberOf=CN=Users,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local))"
```

I have to be sure that this field contains only digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with an LDAP filter.

You may however be able to constrain the attribute, so that non-numerical never get in there in the first place.